# How to deal with pop up messages when running excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a excel macro to help me automatically copy and paste and I need to open and close several spreadsheets. However, a message box pops up when the macro opens/closes a file and I have to manually close the message box to continue run the macro.
Is there any method to automatically close the message box? I tried Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}" but it turned out to be useless.
Thanks!

[image: picture: There is a large amount of information on the clipboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can empty the clipboard after pasting with:

```vb
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

You can suppress alert warning pop ups by enclosing the triggering code such as workbook saves, for example, like this:

```vb
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```